# mysql workbench sqlJoins

Tags: c#, mysql

So i don't understand how joining of tables works in mysql database

(is it from table that has Primary Key to table that has its Foreign Key? or vice versa?)

I always encounter this and I don't know what is the problem

I have used this sql statement and what I want to achieve is to join three tables then get the result and put it in datagridview and in this code that i do is only two table for me to practice and join 3 tables later on.

```
string sql = "SELECT category_information.category, description_information.description" +
             "FROM category_information INNER JOIN description_information ON category_information.type_id" +
             " = description_information.category_information_type_id";
```

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL 
    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
    for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN description_information ON 
    category_information.type_id = description' at line 1'
```

Comment: You need to have a space between `description_information.description` and `FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the "@" prefixing a string allows you to do multiple lines and can thus cleanly read SQL without extra close-quote + signs.  I also changed to utilize table "aliases" for long table names for readability.  Just a sample from your original code would directly see readability.

Yet StuardD's answer was correct.  When you had the strings concatenated together you would not see the obvious, here you would.

```
string sql = 
@"SELECT 
      CI.category, 
      DI.description
   FROM 
      category_information CI
         INNER JOIN description_information DI
            ON CI.type_id = DI.category_information_type_id ";
```